# CSS Grid...my last image continues to appear larger than the others?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Please help me out with a CSS Grid problem that I am having...my last image continues to appear larger than the others in my .featured section when I try switching to grid during a media query @700px.

This is a start to a portfolio of mine, but as I decided to make my .featured section, or my images to be in grid format instead of flex like the rest of the page, suddenly my last image is showing up larger than the others.

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong? I'm stuck right now trying to figure out why this is happening. Thank you!

Here is the link and code to my page: [https://codepen.io/elcapitan23/pen/wxpmYP](https://codepen%2Eio/elcapitan23/pen/wxpmYP)

Also, here is a screen capture of what I am currently dealing with:[Portfolio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHdW5.jpg)

Comment: The link for your code is a image. Update it with proper codepen.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: In addition, the link doesn't demonstrate the issue, since it doesn't have any images.

Comment: I apologize guys. Thanks for looking. I didn't realize that my link was not correct. @Rahul R provided an answer and I was able to fix my problem with his recommendation. Thank you for pointing this out. I am very new to posting on StackOverflow, but I will use your comments as guidelines the next time that I post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css class `.featured-item` has a last-child style

```
 .featured-item:last-child {
   margin-right: 4px;
 }
```

Which is the culprit, either remove this class, or override this style for last div.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/rathorer/pen/bjajdg)

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul. Your feedback made me really look at that class over again, and removed it. With a little bit more styling editing, it looks great! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: Oops. Still learning the ropes here. I just did. Thanks again!